# Iterate through User Defined Array in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to use a User Defined Variable as the Input variable in a ForEach Controller, but the HttpRequest inside the ForEach never fires.

[image]

[image]

Is userList not in scope? Do I need to make it an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) expects JMeter Variables to look like:

```
var_1
var_2
var_3
```

So you need to amend your [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) to look like

[image]

and ForEach Controller to look like:

[image]

this way you get what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: That's not going to work for us.  We're going to have 1000 to 5000 users.

Comment: Then "we" should learn how to properly ask questions, from your "screenshot" I see that "we" have only 4 user IDs. If you have a larger JSON array with several thousands of IDs you can convert it into JMeter Variables using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), see [Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) chapter of Groovy documentation for more details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73873146/jmeter-forcontroller-not-seeing-variables