# JMeter ForController not seeing Variables

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to iterate through a User Defined Array using a ForEach Controller.  I'm looping through the array and for each node, creating a new variable with the iteration count appended to the name. However, the ForEach Controller doesn't ever fire.

[image: Test plan and User Variables]
[image: Create the Variables]
[image: ForEach Controller]
[image: Log of the data]

I can see that the values are created by logging them, but the ForEach Controller doesn't ever make it's HttpRequests.  Please note that this is a prototype, our actual use case will have 1000-5000 nodes in the array and will do more then just an HttpRequest. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The variables must exist prior a thread (virtual user) reaches the ForEach Controller
2. PreProcessors are executed [**before**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) and are not executed without Samplers, so your PreProcessor gets executed **only before** "HTTP Request Not In ForEach"

So the options are in:

1. Replace ForEach Controller with the HTTP Request Not In ForEach so the latter one would appear earlier in the Test Plan
2. Convert JSR223 PostProcessor to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), Samplers are executed consecutively and upside down. If you don't want it to generate a result add [`SampleResult.setIgnore()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) line somewhere in your script. See [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates) for more Groovy-related tips and tricks

Answer (score 0):

PreProcessor is executed before samplers in its scope, so that's why you don't enter the ForEach Controller.

You can change it to JSR223 Sampler, or add Sampler before the For ForEach Controller